# ExcelDNA Memory Space

Tags: memory, interop, mef, excel-dna

I am writing an application that has multiple potential user interfaces and I am using MEF to inject the appropriate implementation during startup. One implementaiton of `IDisplay` uses ExcelDNA (Excel is the interface). The code launches Excel as a process through

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName  = PATH_TO_EXCEL,
    Arguments = PATH_TO_EXCELDNA_ADDIN
};

Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This works fine except that Excel is now in a seperate memory space so UI callbacks (i.e. Ribbon button clicks) cannot get access to any injected or assigned properties.

One possible solution is to launch Excel first then have ExcelDNA's `AutoOpen()` hook (which gets called once the add in has loaded in Excel) call the bootstrapper class to configure MEF however I'm wondering if it is possible to *share* memory between the C# and Excel processes? Would starting Excel via `Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application { Visible = true; }` resolve? I would try this but have not been able to find out how to specify the path of the ExcelDNA addin for it to load (like above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel will always run as a separate process. So you can't share memory between the Excel process and another process. However, C# code can run inside the Excel process - this is exactly how an Excel-DNA add-in works.

You can also communicate between the Excel process and some other process. One option for this is to use the COM Automation interop - this is what you're doing when you call `new Excel.Application` from your own executable. You are starting a separate Excel process (or connecting to an existing running process), and then getting back an inter-process communication proxy (the `Application` object).

If you then want to tell that Excel process to load an Excel-DNA add-in, you can call `Application.RegisterXLL(path_to_add_in)` to have it load the .xll. How you hook up the Excel-DNA add-in and the rest of your code is still to be figured out.

You might still need some kind of cross-process communication, like .NET Remoting, WCF with named pipes or something like that.